# What is the difference in these way of creating a list in Kotlin ? My result1 is valid but result2 is invalid

Tags: kotlin

```
val list1 = listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
val list2 = listOf(1..9)
```

/*
my result1 is valid but result2 gives error
*/

```
val result1= list1.filter{i -> i>2} 

val result2 = list2.filter{i -> i>2}
```

Comment: The second one is a List of IntRanges, where the only element is the range from 1 to 9. If you want to turn an IntRange into a `List<Int>`, do `(1..9).toList()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

is a list of nine numbers — specifically, [`Int`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/)s.

However, `1..9` is a range object — specifically, an [`IntRange`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-range/).  So:

```
listOf(1..9)
```

is a list that contains a single object.

```
list1.filter{ i -> i > 2 }
```

is valid, because `filter()` applies its lambda to each `Int` in the list — and the `>` operator is defined between two `Int`s.  However:

```
list2.filter{ i -> i > 2 }
```

is not valid, because the lambda is applied to the `IntRange`, and you can't compare an `IntRange` to an `Int`.

---

Your IDE and compiler should give you several clues about this.  First, if you hover over `list1` and `list2` you'll see the types that the compiler infers for them: `List<Int>` and `List<IntRange>`, respectively.

And not only does the IDE underline `{ i -> i > 2 }`, it also shows the `>` in red.  Hovering over that shows the error ‘Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch…’  That's a bit cryptic, but you should get to know it, because it's quite common and very useful.  It's telling you that you're trying to call a function/method/operator that's not defined for the type(s) you have.  In this case, `>` (which is equivalent to [`compareTo()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-comparable/compare-to.html)) is defined for two `Int`s, two `Long`s, two `String`s, etc., but *not* for an `IntRange` and an `Int`.

So the compiler doesn't know what return type it should have, and temporarily assumes `Unit` — but `filter()` needs a lambda returning a `Boolean`, which is why the whole lambda is underlined with a ‘Type mismatch’ error.

---

As Tenfour04 says, you can *convert* a range into a list if you need to (using the `toList()` method).  But in practice, that's not needed very often because there's usually a better approach.  (A range takes much less memory than most lists, and is therefore quicker to iterate through; and it implements [`Iterable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-iterable/) so you can already do most list-type things with it anyway.)